# I'm curious as to if you're interested?

Tags: grammar

"I'm curious as to if you're still interested [..]"

Is this valid grammar? I've also thought of 'curious in if you're still interested', neither now sound right and starting to question.

Absent-mindedly placed my phone in tea, the w key isn't working whatsoever, and wondering whether I would be able to use this, or what synonyms I could use in its place.

Comment: Define "valid grammar". It's worth noting that [nearly everyone uses "whether" in this construction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curious+as+to+if%2Ccurious+as+to+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccurious%20as%20to%20whether%3B%2Cc0). But that's obviously irrelevant if your "w" key doesn't ork.

Comment: It's valid in the sense that people say it. But I've never heard 'curious in if...'.

Comment: @Mynamite *Do* people say it? I've never heard *as to if*.

Comment: To me it seems to have the same meaning, my brother also thought it valid, however it's just the blind leading the blind at the moment.

Comment: I don't think broken hardware workarounds are in scope for this site : p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase Little Eva:

> "I'm curious to see if you're interested"

Answer (score 2):

**Grammatically speaking, the answer is no.** 
As far as I know, noun clauses led by *if* cannot serve as the object following a preposition. Therefore, neither "as to if..." nor "in if..." in your sentence is valid.
However, noun clauses led by *if* can serve as the direct object of a transitive verb, so it is ok to say

> I'm curious to know if you're still interested.

where "if you're still interested" serves as the object of *know*. 
Another possible alternative, from a grammatical perspective, is that you can replace *if* by *whether* in your original sentence, because noun clauses led by *whether* can be used almost the same as is an ordinary noun: it can serve as the subject, the noun predicate, or the object of both verbs and prepositions. So you can say

> I'm curious as to whether you're still interested.

This alternative is grammatically correct and sounds acceptable to me, but may not be as good as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Here're some alternatives:

I'm curious. Are you still interested? - *Prosaic*

I'm curious.... you, still interested? - *Informal* ("valid grammar", absent!)

Interested am I. Are you? - *Rhetorical*

(Forget the 'w')